# Vic-20 total game cartridge sales

Tags: history, commodore, game-cartridge, vic-20

The Vic-20, like many home computers of its time, had a cartridge slot that could be used both as a general expansion slot, and for game cartridges like a console. Game cartridges on the Commodore machines faded away later, but seemed to be quite popular at that time: http://www.zimmers.net/anonftp/pub/cbm/vic20/Cartlist-1.9m.txt

Console manufacturers plan on eventually selling several cartridges per machine; this is both natural from the customer viewpoint, and central to the business model from the manufacturer viewpoint, though to Commodore they were more of a sideline.

How many game cartridges were sold per Vic, or in total across all ~2.5 million Vics? I would be interested in either a number by Commodore alone, or by Commodore plus third parties.

Comment: Not an answer, but my own personal experience - I only ever bought one Vic-20 cartridge and it was the Forth language.  Didn't come with anything useful, had to go find a book on Forth.  It was the first complete waste of money I ever spent on "software"  Never could figure it out.

Comment: @Bill I find that somewhat ironic, since sounds to me like _the_ most useful VIC-20 cartridge ever (I had no idea someone had released a FORTH for VIC-20) and if I were going to own an unexpanded VIC-20 and just one cartridge, that would be the one. :-) (I've not done much programming in FORTH, but given the VIC-20's memory limitations, it FORTH would be one of the more useful languages for it.)

Comment: I bought a few carts (games like Jupiter Lander, Radar Rat Race, a few Scott Adams adventures) plus 3K/8K/16K RAM packs, Audiogenic FORTH (practically unusable because the manual was dire), a BUTI+ (like the Programmers Aid cart but 10x better), a hardware speech synthesizer, and the Commodore Machine Code Monitor cart. I also had a 3rd-party 'motherboard', which was what we VIC users called an extension board that plugged into the cart slot and gave you 4 or 6 slots plus onboard memory.